# Netsuite: Is there a way to have dedicated Shipping and Billing Addresses?

Tags: netsuite

It seems that, by default, NS lets you choose any address as either a shipping address or a billing address. In the dropdown where I choose either address it's showing all addresses I've ever created.

Is there a way to classify an address as only, say, a billing address so that address is never an option shipping address in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found any way to only make one option for either, you can make it autofill based off an established default in the customer record.

- Go into the customer record (not the sales order)
- Click on the address tab
- Click on any address

When you click on an address, you can check "Default Billing" and/or "Default Shipping" and the sales orders will auto-populate those given addresses without you having to choose from a dropdown at all.

After you check the addresses you want for default billing and shipping, you can remove all of the other addresses by clicking on them individually and then clicking the remove button that appears under the record. That's if you want to keep them off the drop-downs.

You'll have to keep removing old ones every time you add a new one, but it's the best solution i've come across.

Edit: You can add new shipping/billing and check them as defaults from within the sales order, but you can only remove them in the customer record. When you're in the sales order and you click the plus sign next to the drop-down, the form for their new address will have check boxes at the top for default billing/shipping.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had a customer say he wasn't going to let his own employees use our online store because he was afraid the employees would accidentally have a bill sent to a customer address, since they were all available in the dropdown. So setting a default doesn't cut it in this case, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Ah I see the dilemma. We don't have drop-downs for our customers on the front-end. It's an auto-populated form with their defaults that they can only change by entering new information in the form fields. Have you considered doing something like that? It doesn't leave much room for error.

Comment: Good call. I'm going to play around with that.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good solution. You can always change the default billing address by editing your profile, and that probably doesn't change much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it can be using a beforeLoad userEvent script.

In the before load you have access to form object and fields. You can get the nlobjField and then remove the select options.

Also, you may want to add a custom checkbox field on address (Customization > List, Records & Fields > Other Custom Fields) so, that you can make a call on type of address it is while creating/editing the address